# Currency conversion issue

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, items

I'm having some trouble with a payment module we are going to use.

The issue is that the module, before sending the payment request sum all products, shipping cost to match against Grand total. If the match fail, the transaction will not be processed.
This works perfect for my base currency,which is SEK, however when switching to USD. I can see Grand total to be in USD as well as shipping cost. However my products are yet still in SEK which gives me an error as the grand total amount don't match the "line items".

`$totalAmount = round($order->getGrandTotal(),2);
currencyCode = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();`

How each line is calculatated for products:

`$lineprice = $item->getPrice();
$linetax = $item->getTaxPercent();
$unitAmountExcludingTax =  $item->getPrice();
$linetaxamount = ($lineqty * $lineprice) * ($linetax/100);
$linetotalamount =  $lineqty * $unitAmountExcludingTax + $linetaxamount;`

So should I just try to get something else then "getPrice" or should I do some sort of store to order rate conversion?

Comment: for payment methods I think you should stick with the base currency of your store and what is accepted from that gateway, try using `$order->getBaseGrandtotal()` and so, for the request.

Comment: Thing is that we want to debit the customer in USD, EUR and SEK. We can not debit in SEK on all orders I'm afraid

Comment: I tried testing it with the following: `$item->getData('row_total_incl_tax');` which saves me from calculating it myself and I compared the total of all items against the subtotal `$order->getData('subtotal_incl_tax');` which matched every time , whats left will be to apply the shipping and discounts to make it match the grandtotal as you needed.

Comment: I was able to change from `getPrice` to `getConvertedPrice` that gives me the price in USD. So that pretty much solved it. It created a second issue but I will ask that again

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort it this way. Probably not the perfect solution but worked in my case.
            `if($order->getOrderCurrencyCode() == 'SEK'){
                $lineprice = $item->getPrice();
                $unitAmountExcludingTax = $item->getPrice();
            }else{
                $lineprice = $item->getConvertedPrice();
                $unitAmountExcludingTax = $item->getConvertedPrice();
            }`